# App works fine on initial selection in EditText, but crashes when run on a second selection

Tags: java, android

I've been writing a starter app in Android Studio (after 20 years in assembly, C++, VBA, and 2 years in C#), and I'm having good luck in general.  But I'm stumped on this one.

I have an EditText where I put a sample from voice to text (no punctuation, no caps or quotes or hyphens).  I select a section, and can cleanly, with click of a button, do all caps, initial caps, all hyphens between, surround with quote marks, &c.  I can run each of these in succession, the select being retained by a line that restores it a the end of each click, so in a test case, I have a selection with all of the above enhancements one on top of another.  There seems to be no limit, until I change the selection area.

In the debugger, I see that all the steps are working as expected.  The crash comes only when I attempt to copy the new, second selection into a variable string.

```
sel = txt.substring(sst,snd);// this works fine prior to new select
```

Then the next F7 (Step Into, the least step I can do) takes me to

```
public void onClick(@android.support.annotation.NonNull android.view.View v) { /* compiled code */ }
```

One more F7 and it crashes.

Is there a way to reset the EditText before or after a change of selection that I am neglecting?

Many thanks to all who will comment.

I've gone as deep as I can into the underlying code to find the point of controversy.  I've looked for a way to reset the EditText after finishing with the original selection.

This is the base class shared setup for each of these buttons:

```
package com.example.app5;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditorButton {
    public String txt = "", outtxt = "", sel = "";
    public int sst, snd;
    public EditText t;

    public EditorButton(EditText T) {
        t = T;
        txt = t.getText().toString();
        sst = t.getSelectionStart();
        snd = t.getSelectionEnd();

        sel = txt.substring(sst,snd);
    }
    public void Finish(){
        String newtxt = txt.substring(0,sst) + outtxt + txt.substring(snd);
        t.setText((CharSequence)newtxt);
        t.setSelection(sst, (sst + outtxt.length()));
    }

// Then as an example, one of the inheritors
 public void Q(View view){
        EditorButton eb = new EditorButton(t);
        eb.outtxt = "\"" + eb.txt.substring(eb.sst,eb.snd) + "\"";
        eb.Finish();
    }
```

Expected results, the same as before.
Actual:  first selection great, second one, crash.

Comment: Run the app outside the debugger, then [look at Logcat to see the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this). If you do not grok the stack trace, edit your question and add it.

Comment: OK, I did that, found this line:
    Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=43; regionStart=22; regionLength=-14


So I set a break at the EditorButton line 15 which is
     sel = txt.substring(sst,snd);
ran to the break, ran out of the first stop (which has always worked)
moved the selection to a different substring
ran to the break, then carefully, using all F7s (StepInto)
and — to my amazement — the second selection was processed correctly as well!  No change in the code.  Only the very tiptoe gradual stepping through it.

Weird.  Thanks for LogCat tip tho

Comment: Now it's all working perfectly!   Needed aging, I guess ????